# Deprecated In Groovy 2.1.X but where to find explanation and alternatives?

Tags: groovy, deprecated, gdk

I see that there are many deprecated methods and fields in the GDK (http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/deprecated-list.html).

For example, DefaultGroovyMethods.withObjectInputStream{} is deprecated now.

I need to understand what the alternatives (the new ways) are for the deprecated stuff.

Anyone has any clues on where to look to find more info on the deprecated stuff?

Comment: Found the answer: Looking at the GDK source code I see now that the deprecated methods call their own new replacement method.
eg:

`@Deprecated
    public static <T> T withDataInputStream(File file, Closure<T> closure) throws IOException {
        return ResourceGroovyMethods.withDataInputStream(file, closure);
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as you can see, there was a move to get DefaultGroovyMethods a bit shorter (as it was turning into a huge monolithic static class).

So the methods have been moved into logically grouped classes and the originals deprecated (but call the new location so any existing code tied to DGM will still work for now)

I believe the idea is eventually to remove these deprecated methods.